# Object with MyTrait {}

Tags: scala

`new MyTrait` leads to "trait MyTrait is abstract; cannot be instantiated" but `new MyTrait {}` actually leads to an instance of type `java.lang.Object with MyTrait`. I can understand what is happening (with `java.lang.Object` being sort of a default instance), but what is the role of the `{...}` here? Is this an anonymous implementation?

Comment: yes, it is ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Scala Traits behave?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724284/how-scala-traits-behave)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `{}` you're basically saying "let's instance an object with the given trait, where the abstract part is implemented just once for this instance". So yeah, it's basically an anonymous class that has your trait and can implement all the abstract parts. In this case there are no abstract parts and so `{}` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

From [Scala spec](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates):

> By contrast, the superclass constructor `sc` normally refers to a class which is not a trait. It is possible to write a list of parents that starts with a trait reference, e.g. `mt1` with … with `mtn`. In that case the list of parents is implicitly extended to include the supertype of `mt1` as first parent type.

Technically it doesn't answer why `TemplateBody` is required when `sc` is not defined, but it does answer what would be your object type:

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> trait T extends A
defined trait T

scala> new T
<console>:10: error: trait T is abstract; cannot be instantiated
              new T
              ^

scala> new T {}
res0: A with T = ...
```

Comment: The latter is something completely different: it's an anonymous inner class, exactly like in Java. In Java, the exact same thing is also legal: `new SomeInterface { /* … */ }` means "create an anonymous class which `implements SomeInterface` and instantiate it".